# Rails mailer link for iOS custom URL scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an iOS app with a Rails backend and have setup a custom URL scheme for the app so that opening a link on mobile Safari with myapp:// will launch my app. In Rails, I am trying include such a link in my password reset template (from Devise). But when I use

`<%= link_to "CLICK HERE", "myapp://" %>`

the link generated is not clickable. When I use the same code in views that aren't for mailing the link works fine. What am I missing?

**Updated with html rendered in email**

```
Sent mail to user@example.com (1989ms)
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2013 15:34:06 -0700
From: Support <support@company.com>
Reply-To: Support <support@company.com>
To:user@example.com
Message-ID: <51afbcde21b30_7b5e3fea39834ce0847d@Computer.local.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello user@example.com!</p>
<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the    link below.</p>
<p>If you're accessing this email on an iPhone you can reset your password directly by clicking <a href="myapp://">HERE</a></p>
<p>OR</p>
<p><a href="http://company.com/reset_password?   reset_password_token=bs1ra4mfzJwsyRBdzJoh">Change my password</a></p>
<br>
<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://company.com/users/sign_in
```

Comment: what is the html that gets rendered in your email?

Comment: updated question with the html that's rendered in the email